# Extracting the a system app from stock OTA, then installing it on a custom ROM

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, camera, oneplus

I'm using a OnePlus 9 Pro running crDroid v7. The OnePlus 9 Pro is made in conjunction with Hasselblad, they provide a better camera and accompanying app that utilizes the camera to it's full potential. I installed the custom ROM for it's extra functionality, but there have yet to be good GCAM configs for the special camera, or other camera apps that work good with this model, so I would like to have the stock camera app installed on the custom ROM. Is this possible? The stock ROM for this model is called Oxygen.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I've found an extracted .apk from the indian oxygen, and I've tried installing this .apk using the systemize magisk module. This installs the app, but it doesn't function. Afterwards I found out this was for the 9R, not the 9 Pro.
2. I've found a dump of the OTA, and extracted the /system/priv-app/OnePlusCameraService folder from it. I've tried putting this folder into the /system/priv-app/ folder on my custom ROM. This didn't do anything (visible).
3. Inside the dumped OnePlusCameraService folder, there is an .apk file. I'm guessing that's standard. I've tried installing that .apk file using the systemize magisk module. This cause my phone to get stuck on the booting animation after reboot.

I do not understand the app installation process that well. So I'm kind of at a loss right now. Is there a way for me to extract the stock camera app from the OTA dump, and install it on my custom rom? I forgot to mention the fact that this app does have to be installed as system, otherwise the installation process will simply fail.
OTA Dump: [the dump](https://dumps.tadiphone.dev/dumps/oneplus/oneplus9pro/-/tree/qssi-user-11-RKQ1.201105.002-2104020454-release-keys)

I appreciate all the help I can get! :D

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't install Oxygen OS camera on your OnePlus device running crDroid because the only requirement to run the Oxygen OS app package on an AOSP based ROM isn't the apk from an OTA dump alone. No matter you install it as a system/app or system/priv-app or /system/vendor/priv-app etc, it'll still force close.

You need to port the necessary camera libraries, the apk itself, some props etc to enable it to function on AOSP. YOu might also need the exact stock ROM signature on your device (I assume crDroid is using Pixel 5 signature). All this is really hard even for an experienced dev since OnePlus ofcourse don't want you to get all those special camera features on anything except on the stock ROM.

Googling "Oxygen OS Camera Port" will help you find some port APKs but I'm afraid you would still not get those "Hasselblad" specific features.

Comment: Thank you very much for your structured answer. This fully explains my issue. I'm no where near experienced enough in android Dev. But I have quite some experience in java, so just for my own amusement I'm going to try and pull the apk apart. I will contact the devs of my custom ROM if they have any plans to port the stock app. If not, then so be it. At least I now know whats up. Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome. Neither am I an expert in this porting stuff, else i would have been happier to help you out